# Error When Trying to Run Subquery

Tags: sql-server-2012, subquery, where

I am having issues getting my subquery to run properly.  Everything runs quickly and correctly until I add the subquery.  I get the error:
"Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 66
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','."

```
FROM FactPerson FP
JOIN FactCrash FC ON FP.CrashSK = FC.CrashPK
JOIN DimHWYType DHT ON DHT.HWYTypeCode = FC.HighwayTypeCode
JOIN FactVehicle FV ON FV.CrashSK = FC.CrashPK
JOIN DimVehicleType DVT ON DVT.VehicleTypeCode = FV.VehicleTypeCode
WHERE (FC.HighwayTypeCode = 'A' OR FC.HighwayTypeCode = 'B' OR FC.HighwayTypeCode = 'C')
AND (FV.VehicleTypeCode = 'A' OR FV.VehicleTypeCode = 'B' OR FV.VehicleTypeCode = 'S')
AND (FP.Age, FP.PersonType) IN
    (SELECT FP.Age, FP.PersonType
    FROM FactPerson FP
    WHERE (FP.PersonType = 'A')
    AND (FP.Age BETWEEN 18 AND 21))
```

I've also tried EXISTS, but it returns records that are outside the Age criteria.

```
FROM FactPerson FP
JOIN FactCrash FC ON FP.CrashSK = FC.CrashPK
JOIN DimHWYType DHT ON DHT.HWYTypeCode = FC.HighwayTypeCode
JOIN FactVehicle FV ON FV.CrashSK = FC.CrashPK
JOIN DimVehicleType DVT ON DVT.VehicleTypeCode = FV.VehicleTypeCode
WHERE (FC.HighwayTypeCode = 'A' OR FC.HighwayTypeCode = 'B' OR FC.HighwayTypeCode = 'C')
AND (FV.VehicleTypeCode = 'A' OR FV.VehicleTypeCode = 'B' OR FV.VehicleTypeCode = 'S')
AND EXISTS
    (SELECT FP.Age, FP.PersonType
    FROM FactPerson FP
    WHERE (FP.PersonType = 'A')
    AND (FP.Age BETWEEN 18 AND 21))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AND (a,b) IN (SELECT x,y FROM ... WHERE)` is standard SQL but not yet implemented in SQL Server. You can replace it with a correlated `EXISTS` subquery:

```
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ... AND x=a AND y=b)
```

Your `EXISTS` subquery is not correct because it is not correlated.

In your specific query, it should be written:

```
AND EXISTS 
    (SELECT *
    FROM FactPerson FPi
    WHERE FPi.PersonType = 'A'
    AND FPi.Age BETWEEN 18 AND 21
    AND FPi.Age = FP.Age AND FPi.PersonType = FP.PersonType)
```

But all the subquery is really unnecessary. The simple conditions would be equivalent:

```
AND FP.PersonType = 'A' 
AND FP.Age BETWEEN 18 AND 21
```

Comment: The correlated EXISTS worked perfect!   Thank you SO much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to break apart your `AND (FP.Age, FP.PersonType) IN`part.  The following code parses correctly and should provide the data you want.

```
AND (
        FP.Age
    IN (
        SELECT FP.Age

        FROM FactPerson FP
        WHERE (FP.PersonType = 'A')
            AND (FP.Age BETWEEN 18 AND 21)
        )
        AND FP.person IN (
        SELECT FP.person

        FROM FactPerson FP
        WHERE (FP.PersonType = 'A')
            AND (FP.Age BETWEEN 18 AND 21)
            )
            )
```

Comment: I did that originally; but my professor does not want that.  I tried using EXISTS but it is returning records that are outside the ages of 18 and 21.

Comment: You provided a correct answer but your prof doesn't like it? What is he/she expecting to see? Did you receive guidance about a specific way to accomplish this?

Comment: He liked it but said that there was a more efficient way I could be doing it.  No, just to use subquery.  

This is what I have for the EXISTS but as I said, it's returning records that are outside the Age criteria.

    AND EXISTS
     (SELECT Age
      FROM FactPerson
      WHERE Age BETWEEN 18 AND 21
      AND PersonType = 'A')

Comment: Please include your attempt with EXISTS in your original post

Comment: I just put the EXISTS in the original post.  Thanks.